# How to handle path separators in a php library?

Tags: php

I am developing a php library which loads views from a given folder. I set condiguration values in the library to point to the views, so there will be something like `public $viewFolder = 'Views/DarkTheme/'`.
The dev who uses my library has the OPTION of changing this to something a different folder, but does not have to.

In developing the library, do i need to account for Windows servers in the paths?

So when i get to the point of `include __DIR__.$this->viewFolder.$someViewFile`, do i need to wrap the include path in an `str_replace(['\\', '/'], PATH_SEPARATOR, $filePath)` to ensure it works on windows systems as well?

If so, is there a better way to handle it?

This is quite a simplification of the actual setup, but it does involve hardcoded path separators and i don't think i have a way around that.

Comment: Windows allows both forward and backslash as directory separators.

Comment: BTW, the constant you should be using is `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, not `PATH_SEPARATOR`.

Comment: So you can use Unix-style pathnames on Windows, but not vice versa.

Comment: That's great! And thank you for the clarification. I'm on mobile so i didn't want to bother double checking before i posted.